# Iterating over three variables

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, append

Ok, this is going to be really long. I am trying to calculate water levels in an analytical solution in a polar grid. It depends on both r and theta as well as this variable j. What I am trying to do is essentially calculate a water level at a specific r, theta point in my grid based in a given equation. This equation has a portion where it sums over infinite values of j. Part of the equation is here [Equation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbkDm.png)

Some of the code is as follows:

```
"""
Plot idealized solution for water levels in a quarter circle domain with 
constant bathymetry  
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from pylab import meshgrid,cm,imshow,contour,clabel,colorbar,axis,title,show

# establish parameters
Ho = 300 #m
g = 9.81 #m/s2
r1 = 1000 #m
r2 = 10000 #m
rr = np.arange(r1,r2,10)

#radial size of domain
phi = np.pi/2
#theta is the angle in radians at a specific location within the domain
#theta = np.pi/4

theta = np.arange(0, phi, np.pi/360)#varies
Theta = theta[1:180]

zeta = [0] * len(rr) * len(Theta)
#converting from wind speed to wind shear stress
U = 10
Cd = (1/1000) * ((3/4) + (U/15))
Roair = 1.225 #kg/m3
Rowater = 997 #kg/m3

W = (Roair/Rowater) * Cd * (U**2)

#wind shear in m^2/s^2 in the 0 direction (W to E)
Wo = np.sqrt((W**2)/2)
#wind shear in m^2/s^2 in the phi direction 
Wphi = np.sqrt((W**2)/2)

zeta = np.zeros((len(rr), len(Theta)))
#determines the bathymetry
a_star = []
n = 0
kappa = (1-n)**(0.5)
for t in range(len(Theta)):
    a_star.append ( ( (np.sin(phi)) / (g*Ho*kappa* np.sin(kappa*Theta[t])) ) )

#first half of equation 19 that does not depend on j 
for r in range(len(rr)):
    for t in range(len(Theta)):
        zeta[r,t] = ( (a_star[t] * (rr[r]**(1-n)))*(Wo*np.cos(((1-n)**(0.5))*Theta[t]) + Wphi*np.cos(((1-n)**(0.5))*(Theta[t]-phi))) )  

#second half of equation 19 for j=0    
ajbj = []

for t in range(len(Theta)):
    j = 0
    Djo = np.sin(( ( (1-n)**(0.5) ) * phi ) ) / ( (1-n)**(0.5) * (phi) ) 
    Ejo = (np.sin(phi)) / (phi) 
    ajbj.append (  (r2**(1-n)) * (-a_star[t] * Djo))
    for r in range(len(rr)):
        zeta[r,t] = zeta[r,t] + (ajbj[t])*(Wo+Wphi) 

#second half of equation 19 for j=1,2,3 (summation) 

sj = []
tj = []
Dj = []
Ej = []
r1EogH = []
astarD = []
tjr1r2 = []
sjr2 = []
aj = []
bj = []


jj = [1,2,3]
for j in range(len(jj)):
    sj.append(- (n/2) + np.sqrt( ( (n/2)**2) + ( (jj[j]*np.pi / phi)**2) ) )
    tj.append (- (n/2) - np.sqrt( ( (n/2)**2) + ( (jj[j]*np.pi / phi)**2) ) )    
    Dj.append ( (2* ((-1)**jj[j]) * ((1-n)**(0.5)) * phi * np.sin( ((1-n)**(0.5)) * phi )) / ( (1-n) * (phi**2) - (jj[j]**2) * (np.pi**2) ) )
    Ej.append ( (2* ((-1)**jj[j]) * phi * np.sin(phi) ) / ( (phi**2) - (jj[j]**2) * (np.pi**2) ) )
    r1EogH.append ( ( (r1**(1-n)) * Ej[j] ) / ( g * Ho ) )        
    tjr1r2.append ( tj[j] * (r1**tj[j]) * (r2**sj[j]) )
    sjr2.append ( sj[j] * (r2**tj[j]) )
    for t in range(len(Theta)):
        #astarD.append ( a_star[t] * Dj[j] )
        aj.append (   ( a_star[t]*Dj[j] * (  ( tj[j] * (r1**tj[j]) * (r2**(1-n)) ) - ( (r2**tj[j]) * (r1**(1-n)) ) ) +  ( r1EogH[j] * r2**tj[j] ) ) / ( (sjr2[j] * (r1**sj[j])) - tjr1r2[j] ) )
        bj.append ( ( -1* a_star[t]*Dj[j] * (  ( sj[j] * (r1**sj[j]) * (r2**(1-n)) ) - ( (r2**sj[j]) * (r1**(1-n)) ) ) -  ( r1EogH[j] * r2**sj[j] ) ) / ( (sjr2[j] * (r2**sj[j])) - tjr1r2[j] ) ) 
        for r in range(len(rr)): 
            zeta[r,t] = zeta[r,t] + ( ( (aj[j] * rr[r]**(sj[j])) + (bj[j] * rr[r]**(tj[j])) ) * (Wo*np.cos( (jj[j]*np.pi*Theta[t])/phi)  +  Wphi*np.cos( (jj[j]*np.pi*(Theta[t]-phi))/phi)) )


x,y = np.meshgrid(Theta, rr)

X = Theta
Y = rr

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar='True')
ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, zeta) #X,Y & data2D must all be same dimensions

ax.set_thetamin(0)
ax.set_thetamax(90)

plot = ax.pcolor(zeta)
fig.colorbar(plot)

plt.show()
```

[Solution for above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wSwB.png)
The values I am getting for zeta are much to large. They should be more like the values in the below solution for theta PI/4. I know the equations are complex. What I want is for a point in the grid say r=1000, theta= pi/4 for it to calculate the zeta value for j=1, j=2 and j=3 and then sum those all together and then do the same thing at each point in the grid. I am wondering if I just need to structure my loops differently? Or not use the .append function? Does anyone have any suggestions?

DONE FOR THETA PI/4

```
"""
Plot idealized solution for water levels in a quarter circle domain with 
constant bathymetry  
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from pylab import meshgrid,cm,imshow,contour,clabel,colorbar,axis,title,show

# establish parameters
Ho = 300 #m
g = 9.81 #m/s2
r1 = 1000 #m
r2 = 10000 #m
rr = np.arange(r1,r2,10)
zeta = [0] * len(rr)
#radial size of domain
phi = np.pi/2
#theta is the angle in radians at a specific location within the domain
theta = np.pi/4

#converting from wind speed to wind shear stress
U = 10
Cd = (1/1000) * ((3/4) + (U/15))
Roair = 1.225 #kg/m3
Rowater = 997 #kg/m3

W = (Roair/Rowater) * Cd * (U**2)

#wind shear in m^2/s^2 in the 0 direction (W to E)
Wo = np.sqrt((W**2)/2)
#wind shear in m^2/s^2 in the phi direction 
Wphi = np.sqrt((W**2)/2)

#determines the bathymetry
n = 0
kappa = (1-n)**(0.5)
a_star = ( (np.sin(phi)) / (g*Ho*kappa* np.sin(kappa*theta)) )

#first half of equation 19 that does not depend on j 
for r in range(len(rr)):
    zeta[r] = ( a_star * (rr[r]**(1-n))*(Wo*np.cos(((1-n)**(0.5))*theta) + Wphi*np.cos(((1-n)**(0.5))*(theta-phi))) ) 

#plt.xlabel("rr")
#plt.ylabel("zeta")
###
#plt.plot(rr,zeta, label = 'LHS eq 19') 

#second half of equation 19 for j=0    
for r in range(len(rr)):
    j = 0
    Djo = np.sin(( ( (1-n)**(0.5) ) * phi ) ) / ( (1-n)**(0.5) * (phi) ) 
    Ejo = (np.sin(phi)) / (phi) 
    ajbj =  (r2**(1-n)) * (-a_star * Djo) 
    zeta[r] = zeta[r] + (ajbj)*(Wo+Wphi) 

#plt.xlabel("rr")
#plt.ylabel("zeta")
###
#plt.plot(rr,zeta, label = 'j=0') 

#second half of equation 19 for j=1,2,3 (summation) 

sj = []
tj = []
Dj = []
Ej = []
r1EogH = []
astarD = []
tjr1r2 = []
sjr2 = []
aj = []
bj = []

jj = [1,2,3]
for j in range(len(jj)):
    sj.append(- (n/2) + np.sqrt( ( (n/2)**2) + ( (jj[j]*np.pi / phi)**2) ) )
    tj.append (- (n/2) - np.sqrt( ( (n/2)**2) + ( (jj[j]*np.pi / phi)**2) ) )    
    Dj.append ( (2* ((-1)**jj[j]) * ((1-n)**(0.5)) * phi * np.sin( ((1-n)**(0.5)) * phi )) / ( (1-n) * (phi**2) - (jj[j]**2) * (np.pi**2) ) )
    Ej.append ( (2* ((-1)**jj[j]) * phi * np.sin(phi) ) / ( (phi**2) - (jj[j]**2) * (np.pi**2) ) )
    r1EogH.append ( ( (r1**(1-n)) * Ej[j] ) / ( g * Ho ) )
    astarD.append ( a_star * Dj[j] )
    tjr1r2.append ( tj[j] * (r1**tj[j]) * (r2**sj[j]) )
    sjr2.append ( sj[j] * (r2**tj[j]) )
    aj.append (   ( astarD[j] * (  ( tj[j] * (r1**tj[j]) * (r2**(1-n)) ) - ( (r2**tj[j]) * (r1**(1-n)) ) ) +  ( r1EogH[j] * r2**tj[j] ) ) / ( sjr2[j] * (r1**sj[j]) - tjr1r2[j] ) )
    bj.append (- ( astarD[j] * (  ( sj[j] * (r1**sj[j]) * (r2**(1-n)) ) - ( (r2**sj[j]) * (r1**(1-n)) ) ) -  ( r1EogH[j] * r2**sj[j] ) ) / ( sjr2[j] * (r2**sj[j]) - tjr1r2[j] ) ) 
    for r in range(len(rr)):
        zeta[r] = zeta[r] + ( ( (aj[j] * rr[r]**(sj[j])) + (bj[j] * rr[r]**(tj[j])) ) * (Wo*np.cos( (jj[j]*np.pi*theta)/phi)  +  Wphi*np.cos( (jj[j]*np.pi*(theta-phi))/phi)) )

plt.xlabel("rr")
plt.ylabel("zeta")
plt.title("Wind In at 45 degrees")
#
plt.plot(rr,zeta, label = 'Ho=100m') 

plt.legend(loc='upper right')
```

[Solution for theta 45degrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbkDm.png)

Comment: That code is unmaintable. There are very complex math operations carried out in Python all over the place, every day, but they don't look like that. The approach needs reformulating, I can't even give suggestions sorry, only that that is not the way forward.

Comment: Maybe, if you post a figure with the equation, you can find a good soul that rewrites this mess for you.

Comment: What the error you are getting. I mean, if you want help with coding a function, post the function, you can post an example with an expected output, in order to understand better and to try to help you.

Comment: There has to be a better way to write that. Are all of those undefined variables you're appending to lists, or Numpy arrays? The code is extremely hard to read, even with reference to your equation, and we can't run it because it's not a [mcve].

Comment: Question has been updated. Can add more if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I am not a math wizard. I tried to run your code to see what output it got prior to me trying to refactor it in some way. However, there are errors because things like `sj` from `sj.append()` are not defined in the snippet provided. I do not know how to read the equation provided in your image (math courses were many years ago and not used since college).

As for advice, without fully understanding your problem, the best I can offer you is to consider making functions. This allows you/others to see the code more clearly. Another advantage is for when something changes (seems unlikely with an equation, but perhaps you want to change your input type at some point in the future) the changes are made in smaller pieces.

```
def calculate_j(point_or_other_necessary_input):
  """ do the maths for j """
  return some_equation_or_value_for_j

def calculate_t(point_or_other_necessary_input):
  """ do the maths for t """
  return some_equation_or_value_for_t

def calculate_r(point_or_other_necessary_input):
  """ do the maths for r """
  return some_equation_or_value_for_r

def process_grid(zeta_grid):
  """ process each point in the provided grid"""
  for point in zeta_grid:
    # or whatever makes sense to combine the values/equations
    calculated_sum = calculate_j(point) + calculate_t(point) + calculate_r(point)
    # store value in some reasonable way, probably another grid
  return calculated_points

print(process_grid(zeta))
```

**After further evaluation, and more info from your edit, I have to ask if you really mean to do:**

```
jj = [1,2,3]
for j in range(len(jj)):
```

I'm guessing, without really being sure, that you want `j` to be `1` then `2`, then `3`, no? Currently you are really getting `0`, `1`, `2` because you are iterating over the length of the list, not the items in the list. This is significant not in the first portion where you are getting the values of jj with `jj[j]` but it is in the portion for r where you use `j` instead of `jj[j]` such as in:

```
zeta[r] = zeta[r] + ( ( (aj[j] * rr[r]**(sj[j])) + (bj[j] * rr[r]**(tj[j])) )
```

**As stated, that could be your intended behavior to only use 0,1,2 instead of 1,2,3.** As for why the values might be too large, do you intend to calculate r for all of rr 3 times? You have it nested inside of the first for loop which means it is executing in every iteration of the `for j in ...` loop. So it is adding to itself (`zeta[r] = zeta[r] + ...`) some large number of times. (Again, not a math person) but isn't that running len(rr)^3 times or 3^len(rr) times? Some number of times more than possibly intended.

Comment: Thank you! This is a good place for me to start. Any way for me to simplify this is helpful.

Comment: Also, I added all of my code above, so hopefully it is repeatable

Comment: See my edit. I believe some of your error could be in your access of 'j'. If you only ever use the value of 'j' you could simplify your life by accessing the values directly in your for-loop. i.e. 'for j in jj:'

Answer (score 1):

Suggest writing a function zeta (r, t, j) that you can test with some hand-calculated values:

```
def zeta(r, theta, j):
   #your complex calculations here

assert zeta(4000, pi/4, 2) == 0.00043 #This is a test to be sure your formulae 
                                      # are right (eyeballed from your graph)
```

Then iterate over rr and theta to fill the array:

```
zeta_out = np.zeros((len(rr), len(Theta)))

for r in range(len(rr)):
    for t in range(len(theta)):
        zeta_out[r, t] = np.mean(zeta(rr[r], theta[t], j) for j in (1,2,3))
```